# Iterate over multiple dataframes and perform maths functions save output

Tags: python, loops, variables, for-loop, dataframe

I have several dataframes on which I an performing the same functions - extracting mean, geomean, median etc etc for a particular column (PurchasePrice), organised by groups within another column (GORegion). At the moment I am just performing this for each dataframe separately as I cannot work out how to do this in a for loop and save separate data series for each function performed on each dataframe.

i.e. I perform median like this:

```
regmedian15 = pd.Series(nw15.groupby(["GORegion"])['PurchasePrice'].median(), name = "regmedian_nw15")
```

I want to do this for a list of dataframes `[nw15, nw16, nw17]`, extracting the same variable outputs for each of them.

I have tried things like :

```
listofnwdfs = [nw15, nw16, nw17]

for df in listofcmldfs:
       df+'regmedian' = pd.Series(df.groupby(["GORegion"])
       ['PurchasePrice'].median(), name = df+'regmedian')
```

but it says "can't assign to operator"

I think the main point is I can't work out how to create separate output variable names using the names of the dataframes I am inputting into the for loop. I just want a for loop function that produces my median output as a series for each dataframe in the list separately, and I can then do this for means and so on.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First, `df+'regmedian' = ...` is not valid Python syntax. You are trying to assign a value to an expression of the form `A + B`, which is why Python complains that you are trying to re-define the meaning of `+`.

Also, `df+'regmedian'` itself seems strange. You are trying to add a DataFrame and a string.

One way to keep track of different statistics for different datafarmes is by using dicts. For example, you can replace

```
listofnwdfs = [nw15, nw16, nw17]
```

with

```
dict_of_nwd_frames = {15: nw15, 16: nw16, 17: nw17}
```

Say you want to store `'regmedian'` data for each frame. You can do this with dicts as well.

```
data = dict()
for key, df in dict_of_nwd_frames.items():
        data[(i, 'regmedian')] =  pd.Series(df.groupby(["GORegion"])['PurchasePrice'].median(), name = str(key) + 'regmedian')
```

Comment: Ahh yes, i needs to change to key in the third line but that worked perfectly thank you so much for your help!! I stored the output in a dataframe instead which worked fine :)